# Generate all possible sequences from an Enumerable<int>

Tags: c#, linq, algorithm, c#-4.0

Given List {1,2,3,4,5}

I want to generate all possible sequences of those numbers in C#.

1,2,3,4,5
1,2,3,5,4
etc

It would be good if it was lazy evaluated, but it is not a necessity.

Should return

```
IEnumerable<IEnumerable<int>>
```

My intention is to wrap this into a custom LINQ operator ("permutate" or something). But any good algorithm will be a good start.

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try something like this:

```
    public static IEnumerable<List<T>> GetPermutations<T>(IEnumerable<T> items)
    {
        if (!items.Any()) 
            yield return new List<T>();
        foreach (var i in items)
        {
            var copy = new List<T>(items);
            copy.Remove(i);
            foreach(var rest in GetPermutations(copy))
            {
                rest.Insert(0, i);
                yield return rest;
            }
        }
    }

    public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>>  GetEnumPermutations<T>(IEnumerable<T> items )
    {
        return GetPermutations(items);
    }
```

of course you can change the List-implementation in there but internaly I would stick to some collection because the remove is easier to handle (.Where is possible but not as readable or performant)

Comment: It would be good idea to check if items have 1 or 0 items inside

Comment: yes - sorry (I had this but decided to shorten ... argh) - changed it back, thanks a lot Piotr

Comment: It certainly works. I am staring at it. I don't get what's going on. I can see that it progresses recursively with a smaller and smaller list till it hits the null list. Then it uses the "i" variable in the call stack to compose a sequence. The algorithm wont "snap" into place in my brain though (for example how duplicate values "i" are avoided in the return sequences). Is this some known algorithm, are you just pure genius or is this approach obvious to most except me?

Comment: It is more or less a known algorithm - or more precise it's the way you proof that there are n! permutations for a set of n elements. You just have n choices for your first element (the first foreach) and then you say, hey I have (n-1) Elements left after leaving this (copy.Remove) - so I know inductive (recursive) how to do this (call GetPermutation again) - so just prepend the choice-element to all I got from the recursive call and concatenate all this (second foreach + yield), as Piotr pointed out you just have to take care of the case when the rest is empty (just yield a empty list)

Comment: It works like this (for [1,2,3]): take 1, rest is [2,3] - get recursively the permutation of the rest (= [2,3], [3,2]), prepend your choice (= [1,2,3], [1,3,2]), and go on with the next choice - take 2, rest is [1,3] - get rest (= [1,3], [3,1]), prepend (= [2,1,3], [2,3,1]) and go on with the next choice - take 3, rest is [1,2], get rest (= [1,2],[2,1]), prepend (= [3,1,2], [3,2,1]) and concatenate all you got ... done

Comment: Thank you. The proof I remember for n! possible permutations was that for the sequence [1,2] there are three places where the 3 can be put (before,between,after), thus you multiply permutations of the [1,2] set with 3. And 4 will have four candidate places etc. I get it, but I'm not grokking it. I'm still impressed and slightly disturbed that I have such a hard time over such a pure algorithm. Maybe this will be a printout in my wallet ;)  Thanks again.

Comment: How much effort would be required to make this return all 1, 2, ... n-1 length subsets in addition to the current set?

Comment: only subsets (so [1,2] = [2,1])? This should not be too difficult - the algorithm is allmost the same (you will pass a "subset count" parameter through the recursive call and you have to change it a bit so you don't get reordered items) - think about it yourself or ask another question :)

Comment: items.Count() == 0 should be items.Any() no need to iterate the whole list to figure out if it has at least 1 element

Answer (score 0):

```
    List<int> li = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    var ff = from a in li
             join b in li on 1 equals 1
             join c in li on 1 equals 1
             join d in li on 1 equals 1
             join e in li on 1 equals 1
             where 
             a != b && b != c && c != d && d != e &&
             a != c && b != d && c != e &&
             a != d && b != e && 
             a != e 
             select new { a, b, c, d, e };
```

Comment: and what if there not 5 elements in the list? This is almost as bad as enumerating all permutations by yourself ;) - better change this or delete it. I will not give a new member a downvote based on that but others might do